# Android: Frame Animation stretches to view size

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to make frame animation stay within the center of the image view in which the animation is playing BEFORE the image is downloaded. Basically its an animation for a loading spinner. Here is my imageview in xml file.

```
<TableRow
          android:gravity="center"  >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewUrl1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="94dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="OnClickThumbnail"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
                android:src="@drawable/frameblack" />
```

Here is my frame xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:oneshot="false" >  
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/framezero" android:duration="60" /> 
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/frameone" android:duration="60"  />  
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/frametwo" android:duration="60" />  
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/framethree" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/framefour" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/framefive" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/framesix" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frameseven" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frameeight" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/framenine" android:duration="60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frameten" android:duration="60"  /> 

</animation-list>
```

and here is the code i m using to start the animation

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewUrl1);   
        AnimationDrawable yourAnimation;   

        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);   
        yourAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
                yourAnimation.start();
```

The problem is that the animation stretches the entire width and height of the imageview. The imageview is set to fitCenter. How can i avoid this stretch?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same probelm , the problem is because the animation using background

the solution is :

1. create xml bitmap in drawble folder with the picture for animationList and set the gravity to center

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:gravity="fill|center"
     android:src="@drawable/btn_wifi_anim_3" >

   </bitmap>
   ```
2. set the width of animation layout at runtime like the Height.

   ```
   wifiAnim.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wifiAnim.getHeight(),  wifiAnim.getHeight()));
   ```